# how to read query string from a URL in PHP

Tags: php

If the URL is https://www.mohsin.com?main=17&street=71, then what is the PHP code to grab the "main" and "street" values?

Comment: `$_GET['main']` and `$_GET['street']`

Comment: `$_GET['main']` and `$_GET['street']`?

Comment: don't forget filter values

Answer (score 8):

Try with this :

```
<?php
    $main = $_GET['main'];
    $street = $_GET['street'];
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just call the following function:

```
function getQueryParameter($url, $param) {
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    if (array_key_exists('query', $parsedUrl)) {
        parse_str($parsedUrl['query'], $queryParameters);
        if (array_key_exists($param, $queryParameters)) {
            return $queryParameters[$param];
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

- `$parameter = getQueryParameter('https://www.mohsin.com?main=17&street=71', 'main')` will return `17`.
- `$parameter = getQueryParameter('https://www.mohsin.com?main=17&street=71', 'street')` will return `71`.
- `$parameter = getQueryParameter('https://www.mohsin.com?main=17&street=71', 'invalid')` will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`$main = $_GET['main']` will get the main variable and `$street = $_GET['street']` will get the street variable. All URL parameters are loaded into the PHP $_GET super global array and the super global is an associative array.